# Python; working with instance variable created by a method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, python-object

Im a bit of a beginner when it comes to classes.

I have a class defined as follows (simplified for purposes of this post)

```
class worksheet:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = (filename).strip().replace(" ","")
    def idMaker(self):
        number = '{:05d}'.format(random.randrange(1,99999))
        sheetId = self.filename+str(number)
```

I want to be able to get the 'sheetID' for each instance by saying something like the following (again, this might be completely incorrect):

```
newSheet = worksheet('testsheet')
id = newSheet.sheetID
```

This of course does not work, but I am not sure what I need to do to make it work.

I want to make sure the ID stays constant and doesnt recreate itself with new random numbers.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just generate and assign the `id` in `__init__`. In general, as a user of the class, you don't want to care about generating the `id` yourself. As far as you're concerned, instantiating `Worksheet` gives you a complete, usable object.

```
import random

class Worksheet(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename.strip().replace(' ','')

        number = '{:05d}'.format(random.randrange(1,99999))
        self.sheet_id = self.filename + str(number)

sheet = Worksheet(' some filename with spaces ')
print(sheet.filename)
print(sheet.sheet_id)
```

will output

```
somefilenamewithspaces
somefilenamewithspaces68237
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sheetId` variable lives within that class's `idMaker` method, so you cannot access it with a dot operator. If you are trying to create custom IDs for instances of your class, I would recommend doing that in the class constructor `__init__` method so it gets assigned on object creation. Maybe consider the following:

```
class worksheet:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = (filename).strip().replace(" ","")
        number = '{:05d}'.format(random.randrange(1,99999))
        self.sheetID = self.filename+str(number)
```

Comment: Not quite right. A new random number is generated with each call, and that does not make for an id

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Yea, I'll strike that from my initial answer. I didn't catch that on my first time through the question.